# I want to show all data and after selecting dropdown data will be change in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have made a simple php and jquery based program. In which when a page is open then I want to show all category data first and All is selected. And then when change category by dropdown then data will be display according to selected Category. 
But using this change function of jquery how to do that.

Two files:
index.php file

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db('myproject', $db) or die("Could not select database");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from category");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#select_category").change(function(){
                    var catid  = $("#select_category option:selected").val();
                    $.ajax({
                       type : "post",
                       url : "product.php",
                       data: { id:catid },
                       success: function (response) {
                                var getres = $.parseJSON(response);
                                var results = "";
                                results += "<table border='1'>";
                                results += "<tr>"+
                                                "<th>Product Name</th>"+
                                                "<th>Category</th>"+ 
                                                "<th>Publish</th>"+
                                            "</tr>";

                                    $.each(getres.data , function (key,value){
                                            results += "<tr><td>" + value.product_name + "</td><td>" + value.publish + "</td><td>" + value.category + "</td></tr>";
                                    });
                                    results+= "</table>";
                                    $(".result-container").html(results);
                            }
                    });
                });
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="cat" id="select_category">
        <option value="0">--All--</option>
        <?php  
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  
            <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['cat_name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select><br><br><br>
    <div class="result-container">
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

product.php file

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db('myproject', $db) or die("Could not select database");
$cat_id = $_POST['id'];
     $query = "SELECT p.name AS product_name,CASE WHEN p.publish='yes' THEN '+' ELSE '-' END AS publish,c.cat_name AS categoryFROM product p LEFT JOIN category c ON c.cat_id = p.category";
    if(!empty($cat_id)){
        $query = $query. 'WHERE p.category='.$cat_id;
    }
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $result=array('data'=>$rows);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by calling same ajax code on page load with empty category id.

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'testing') or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db('myproject', $db) or die("Could not select database");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from category");
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function ajaxCall(catid = '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "product.php",
                    data: { id: catid },
                    success: function(response) {
                        var getres = $.parseJSON(response);
                        var results = "";
                        results += "<table border='1'>";
                        results += "<tr>" +
                            "<th>Product Name</th>" +
                            "<th>Category</th>" +
                            "<th>Publish</th>" +
                        "</tr>";

                        $.each(getres.data, function(key, value) {
                            results += "<tr><td>" + value.product_name + "</td><td>" + value.publish + "</td><td>" + value.category + "</td></tr>";
                        });
                        results += "</table>";
                        $(".result-container").html(results);
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                ajaxCall();
                $("#select_category").change(function() {
                    var catid = $("#select_category option:selected").val();
                    ajaxCall(catid);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="cat" id="select_category">
            <option value="0">--All--</option>
            <?php
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="result-container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```